# WPF - Converter with xpath binding get value truncated

Tags: c#, wpf, xpath, converters

I have a WPF TextBox with an xpath binding of a string date:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 0 0 2" IsReadOnly="True" 
    Text="{Binding XPath='ns:data_creazione/text()'}" />
```

When app is running I see a value like this:

```
2016-06-13 22:00:00.000+0000
```

I need to have date formatted in a "readable" format according to machine CultureInfo and I need also the time "converted" to the local time zone, so I made a converter:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace MyNamespace.Converter.General
{
    class DateTimeToLocalTimezoneConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffzzz";

            CultureInfo currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            var date = value as string;

            DateTime valueDate;

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, dateFormat, currentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out valueDate))
            {
                return String.Format("{0:f}", valueDate.ToString(currentCulture));
            }
            return "";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

In xaml I have added static resource declaration and I have modified the TextBox like this:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 0 0 2" IsReadOnly="True" 
    Text="{Binding XPath='ns:data_creazione/text()', 
    Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToLocalTimezoneConverter}}" />
```

Running the code, in my window I see an empty TextBox. Adding a break point inside the Convert method I can see that value is truncated and the TryParseExact return false when parsing the date.
In value param I can see this:

```
2017-02-27T17:06:06
```

What's wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like [`DateTime.TryParseExact` is failing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to parse the string you're giving it. When you say *"I can see that value is truncated"*, can you communicate more specifically precisely what you mean by that? What is the exact truncated value? Which line truncates it? It's hard to say why a method fails without knowing the parameters that were passed in.

Comment: value parameter is `2017-02-27T17:06:06`, but the real value is `2016-06-13 22:00:00.000+0000` as I mentioned in the beginning of my post

Comment: Looks like you're telling it to expect `...HH:mm:ss.fffzzz` and only giving it `...HH:mm:ss`. Are you unable to determine where or how it gets truncated? Or does "real value" mean something other than the actual string value of the `value` parameter to `Convert()` at runtime?

Comment: In XML I have `2016-06-13 22:00:00.000+0000`, without using a converter I see that. When I use the converter, the string value of `value` parameter inside `Convert()` is `2017-02-27T17:06:06`, but I don't know why it gets truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `DateTime.TryParse` method with the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal`:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(date, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out valueDate))
{
    return String.Format("{0:f}", valueDate.ToString(currentCulture));
}
```

Working sample code:

```
CultureInfo currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
string date = "2016-06-13 22:00:00.000+0000";
DateTime valueDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(date, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out valueDate))
{
    string s = String.Format("{0:f}", valueDate.ToString(currentCulture));
}
```

Comment: TryParse seems to work, but the parsing isn't correct. The date string in xml is `2016-06-13 22:00:00.000+0000` but I get `14/06/2016 00:00:00` after parsing.

Comment: Try to use the DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal style instead of DateTimeStyles.None. I edited my answer.

Comment: Now it seems to work using DateTimeStyles. 
None, I can see the right date/time with  timezone adjustment. 
Thank you.